# UITabBar items title issue, when the title is long and using UITabBarAppearance

Tags: swift, uitabbar, ios15, uiappearance, xcode13

Because of iOS 15’s scrollEdgeAppearance transparent problem, I have to use UITabBarAppearance to set my UITabBar. But when using UITabBarAppearance, if the title is long, it will overflow the item area.

↓This is before I add scrollEdgeAppearance. I only implemented UITabBarController and UIViewController to display, without any appearance setting.

[iPhone SE (1st generation)(15.2)(Xcode 13.2.1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JPts.png)
(I can't embed images in my post yet so it is a link)

When I added these code:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *){
   let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
   UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance

   if #available(iOS 15.0, *){
      UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
   }
}
```

↓It will be like this:

[iPhone SE (1st generation)(15.2)(Xcode 13.2.1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYZk9.png)(I can't embed images in my post yet so it is a link)

As you can see that “VeryLongTitle” overlaps into each other, and short “title”s are fine.

I think it is an API bug, but I couldn't find any workaround to fix it.

(I already tried this issue’s answer, and it didn’t work: [iOS TabBar item title issue in iOS13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641202/ios-tabbar-item-title-issue-in-ios13)
so I think it is a different bug.)

Does anyone know how to fix it?